# Bootstrap Grid System (textbox size and columns)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I was wandering if not adding up columns to 12 will affect anything. I have a form and i wanted to shrink the text-box which i had trouble doing and it shrank when i changed 10 to 6 on the bootstrap grid. I have tested on my iPhone 7+ screen and my browser on computers and i have shrank browser windows on computers.  Also, is there a better way to shrink the text box to make it stay smaller. I don't like long text boxes.

I have tried a bunch of stuff but the only way i could figure out how to shrink the textbox was shrinking the 12 to 6. I would like a better way that will keep it 1 size but this way seems like it would never leak over the

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to design these things is

- First you think from the smallest device and then to the largest,
- Specify the size for the smallest first. And check. And Then specify the larger sizes also. `col-xs-1`,`col-sm-2` etc.
- And then you need to check in different devices that how it works.

**For your case specify the size of the `div` maybe `col-xs-12` and `col-md-2` for the text box will do.**

[Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#examples)

You can check Bootstrap Documentation and examples provided there. It is really a helpful material. Change these examples and play with it...you will understand better.